# Centering with CSS not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css

This is driving me crazy.  It works in Chrome, I need it work in IE as well.  https://jsfiddle.net/h18uwtsf/1/

my html

```
<div id="q-numbers">
  <div>Defect Incident as of <span id="qval1"></span></div>
  <div class="table">
    <div>
      <div>Days since last escape</div>
      <div>Best Streak
        <br/>(since 4/5/16)</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="square orange"><span id="qval2">23</span></div>
      <div class="square blue"><span id="qval3">44</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my css

```
#q-numbers > div:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

#q-numbers .table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

#q-numbers .table > div {
  display: table-row;
}

#q-numbers .table > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#q-numbers .table > div > div > div {
  padding: 4px 0px;
}

#q-numbers .blue,
#q-numbers .orange {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #707376;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #707376;
  height: 80px;
}

#q-numbers .square span {
  height: auto;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1, 1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1, 1);
  font-size: 3.5vw;
    }

#q-numbers .footer {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
```

The results I am getting above can be see in my JSFiddle but the numbers are supposed to center in the gray boxes.  In IE they are appearing halfway through the top.

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. It would also be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 2):

Since those elements (`#q-numbers .blue`/`#q-numbers .orange`) are a `table-cell`, the only thing you need is to remove all but font size from the `span` and add `vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;` to them.

See comments in below CSS

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h18uwtsf/5/)

Stack snippet

```css
#q-numbers > div:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

#q-numbers .table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

#q-numbers .table > div {
  display: table-row;
}

#q-numbers .table > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#q-numbers .table > div > div > div {
  padding: 4px 0px;
}

#q-numbers .blue,
#q-numbers .orange {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #707376;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #707376;
  height: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;                 /*  added  */
  text-align: center;                     /*  added  */
}

#q-numbers .square span {                 /*  deleted all but font size  */
  font-size: 3.5vw;
}

#q-numbers .footer {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="q-numbers">
  <div>Defect Incident as of <span id="qval1"></span></div>
  <div class="table">
    <div>
      <div>Days since last escape</div>
      <div>Best Streak
        <br/>(since 4/5/16)</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="square orange"><span id="qval2">23</span></div>
      <div class="square blue"><span id="qval3">44</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using position absolute is not the right way of centering. Use CSS on parent div instead. see this update solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/h18uwtsf/2/

```
#q-numbers > div:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

#q-numbers .table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

#q-numbers .table > div {
  display: table-row;
}

#q-numbers .table > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#q-numbers .table > div > div > div {
  padding: 4px 0px;
}

#q-numbers .blue,
#q-numbers .orange {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #707376;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #707376;
  height: 80px;
}

#q-numbers .square span {
  height: auto;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1, 1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1, 1);
  font-size: 3.5vw;
}

#q-numbers .footer {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.square {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```